# Explorer Shell - Password Protection

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I can already hook into the Shell and perform custom drag drop actions on files, but I'd like to take it a step further but after researching this a while I am unsure of whether it's possible or not.

How can I programmatically password-protect a Folder or Library folder? If this is possible, does Windows have something that can already handle the password protection for us, and we just check on that or do we need to manage the protection on this said folder ourselves, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Windows's security is based on user authentication and authorization, so if you want to deny access to a user, deny the user from the folder's ACL. You can log out and log in as an authorized user to access file (if you accept that as password-protected).

If you do not use Windows's integrated security you need to put the file away from the local file system as Windows Explorer won't challenge you again if you already have a windows credential. Candidate locations include a file server that does not use integrated Windows authentication (e.g. a WebDAV share from Skydrive or a local FTP server), or a password-protected zip file.